# Отправка почты средствами PHP через WAMP server

Tags: php, email, sendmail

Здравствуйте! Обращаюсь к тем, кто смог настроить на локальном сервере отправку почты средствами PHP. Очень необходима ваша помощь.

Использую протокол IMAP(gmail или yandex)  и SMPT-сервер sendmail. При отправке постоянно происходит ошибка «Connect timed out.», много всего прочитал, возможно кто-то смог решить данную проблему или может необходимо использовать другой сервер для отправки почты.

Подключены расширения PHP: open_ssl, sockets;

Модуль Apache: ssl_module.

Система Windows 7, сервер WAMP Apache, php 5.

**PHP-код:**

```
$to       = em1@gmail.com';
$subject  = 'Testing sendmail.exe';
$message  = 'Hi, you just received an email using sendmail!';
$headers  = 'From: em2@gmail.com' . "\r\n" .
            'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n" .
            'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8';

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers))
    echo "Email sent";
else
    echo "Email sending failed";
```

**Файл sendmail.ini (всё необходимое для изменения) :**

- smtp_server=smtp.gmail.ru
- smtp_port=25
- smtp_ssl=none
- default_domain=localhost
- error_logfile=error.log
- debug_logfile=debug.log
- auth_username=my_user_name
- auth_password=my_user_passw
- pop3_server=
- pop3_username=
- pop3_password=
- force_sender= em2@gmail.com
- force_recipient=
- hostname=gmail.com

**Файл php.ini раздел [mail function]**

```
; For Win32 only.
;SMTP = localhost
;smtp_port = 25

; For Win32 only.
;sendmail_from = 
;  -i
sendmail_path = "D:\Server\bin\wamp\sendmail\sendmail.exe -t"
;mail.force_extra_parameters =
mail.add_x_header = On
```

**Файл crach.log:**

```
15.07.08 09:10:31 : Connect timed out.
```

**Файл debug.log:**

```
15.07.08 09:10:21 ** --- MESSAGE BEGIN ---
15.07.08 09:10:21 ** To: em1@gmail.com 
15.07.08 09:10:21 ** Subject: Testing sendmail.exe 
15.07.08 09:10:21 ** X-PHP-Originating-Script: 0:test.php 
15.07.08 09:10:21 ** From: em2@gmail.com 
15.07.08 09:10:21 ** MIME-Version: 1.0 
15.07.08 09:10:21 ** Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8 
15.07.08 09:10:21 ** 
15.07.08 09:10:21 ** Hi, you just received an email using sendmail! 
15.07.08 09:10:21 ** --- MESSAGE END --- 
15.07.08 09:10:21 ** Connecting to smtp.gamil.com:25  
15.07.08 09:10:31 ** Disconnected.
15.07.08 09:10:31 ** Disconnected.
15.07.08 09:10:31 ** Disconnected.
15.07.08 09:10:31 ** Disconnected.
15.07.08 09:10:31 ** Connect timed out.
```

**Часть файла crach.txt:**

```
exception class   : EIdConnectTimeout  <p>
exception message : Connect timed out.  <p>

main thread ($2740): <p>
0041fa42 +000e sendmail.exe IdException                   112   +1 EIdException.Toss <p>
0044092e +014e sendmail.exe IdIOHandlerStack              279  +38 DoConnectTimeout <p>
00440b4c +01d8 sendmail.exe IdIOHandlerStack              346  +55 TIdIOHandlerStack.ConnectClient <p>
00444a9f +0063 sendmail.exe IdIOHandlerSocket             335  +13 TIdIOHandlerSocket.Open <p>
0044157d +0235 sendmail.exe IdTCPClient                   318  +53 TIdTCPClientCustom.Connect <p>
00445cc8 +00a4 sendmail.exe IdExplicitTLSClientServerBase 257  +23 TIdExplicitTLSClient.Connect <p>
0045ab7b +0017 sendmail.exe IdSMTP                        373   +2 TIdSMTP.Connect <p>
004b5f14 +1060 sendmail.exe sendmail                      808 +326 initialization
76533378 +0010 kernel32.dll     <p>                                    BaseThreadInitThunk <p>

thread $2570: <p>
774b01a2 +0e ntdll.dll     NtWaitForMultipleObjects <p>
76533378 +10 kernel32.dll  BaseThreadInitThunk <p>
```

Comment: `15.07.08 09:10:21 ** Connecting to smtp.gamil.com:25` - на самом деле так или результат редактирования? Это имя не резвится в DNS.

Comment: В файле-отчёте так написано

Comment: А в `sendmail.ini` именно `smtp_server=smtp.gmail.ru` ?

Comment: опечатка) .com)

Comment: и точно не `gamil`, как в отладочном дампе? Попробуйте вместо 25 указать порт 587.

Comment: пробовал и 465 и 587 и 25 ни с какими не работает

Comment: А в отладочном дампы оно всё так же пытается `Connecting to smtp.gamil.com:XXX` (с неправильным именем хоста)? Если всё правильно, можете ли вы с этой же машины установить соединение вручную `telnet smtp.gmail.com 25`? Если нет - копайте настройки файрвола на машине, разрешены ли исходящие соединения. Проверьте, чтобы sendmail не был ограничен настройками для работы только на loopback интерфейсе.

Comment: *smtp_ssl=none* — вот это явно неправильно. *plain-text-ом* гугловские сервера аутентификацию вряд ли примут.

Comment: и коннектиться надо [либо на *Port 465 (SSL required)*, либо на *Port 587 (TLS required)*](https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=en)

Comment: Я пользуюсь http://www.mailgun.com/ для локальной разработки. очень удобно

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот работающий, только что проверял.

```
[sendmail]
smtp_server=smtp.googlemail.com
smtp_port=465
smtp_ssl=auto
error_logfile=log/error.log
debug_logfile=log/debug.log
auth_username=*************@gmail.com
auth_password=*************
pop3_server=
pop3_username=
pop3_password=
force_sender=*************@gmail.com
force_recipient=
hostname=*************@gmail.com
```